# Is it a override or subclass

Tags: java, overriding, subclass

I have this method, method1, in class Xxx

The same method exists in this class Yyy, which extends Xxx
But the only difference is that what happens inside the method is not the same, other than that everything is perfectly fine.

So is this called override? or a subclass?

tks.
p.s if need code I have but dont want to make things complicated.

Comment: [Method overriding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) vs [subclasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). The two are not mutually exclusive; in fact, you cannot override a method without some form of subclassing.

Comment: your name is very befitting...

Comment: I suggest following through the [Java "OO" Trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) or other suitable resources. This is well-documented.

Comment: Pls watch your grammar formatting.

Comment: @JackyBoi - your comment doesn't make sense.  The phrase "grammar formatting" is not meaningful because the OP is not formatting any grammar here.  (Perhaps you meant "grammar and formatting".  Or "grammar usage".)

Answer (score 1):

`Yyy` is a subclass of `Xxx`.  "subclass" basically means the same thing as "extends".  By defining `method1` on `Yyy`, you are overriding the definition provided by `Xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

That's called overriding of the method. The class Yyy is subclassing Xxx, and the method being redefined in the subclass is overriding the one in the superclass. To verify that this is true, annotate the method in the subclass with `@Override`.

Answer (score 1):

you are overriding a method in your subclass. a subclass is a class which extends from a super class using **extends** keyword. and overriding only comes into picture when you there is an inheritencerelationship, i.e., a class extends another class.

however, overriding method must satisfy below rules:

1. method name should be the same
2. return types should be same/subtype(in case of co-variant returns)
3. method signature should be the same(i.e., number & type of arguments must match )
4. must not have most restrictive access modifier
5. may have least restrictive access modifier
6. must not throw new or broader exceptions

Comment: ok according to your criteria for a overriding then mine is definetly not overriding tks!

Comment: I can't tell that unless I see your methods